# Connection between the limiting cones

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be categories, and let $T\colon A\to B$ and $S\colon B\to C$ be functors. In this situation, we can consider the following two properties:

**Property 1**: For any limiting cone $\alpha\colon\Delta_c\to S$ the cone $T^*(\alpha)\colon\Delta_c\to S\circ T$ is also limiting.

**Property 2**: For any limiting cone $\beta\colon\Delta_c\to S\circ T$ there exists a unique limiting cone $\alpha\colon\Delta_c\to S$, such that $T^*(\alpha)=\beta$.

**Question**: Are there names for these properties(are they well-known and studied)? If not, whether they can be reduced to some more well-known properties (eg, preservation, creation of limits, etc.)?

Comment: If $T$ is **coinitial** (or **initial**, according to some authors) then it has properties 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we quantify over $S$, Property 1 means that that $T$ is a [final functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor). But then it also has Property 2.

Comment: (Co)finality is about colimits, however.